# How I can put png image as gui icon with Python, tkinter or customtkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

I dont find the way to put image png as icon of GUI window with customtkinter 5.2,tkinter and Python 3.11. i've realized many ways y and dont works anything. Can somebody help me?

I hope my image PNG will convert as icon of the window.

Comment: You can use `iconphoto()` to set the icon in the title bar using a PNG image.

Comment: Also sharing a working code example would make it a bit easier to understand your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Inconphoto, It works in (False,image),right? I've seen that other using the that way. Is the correct form? Because I've used at True y and don't works but I don't understand how it works really.

Comment: If you use `iconphoto()` with `customtkinter`, you need to delay the call by at least 200ms using `.after()` because `customtkinter` also calls `iconbitmap()` using `.after(200, ...)`.